# Exporting an image on the browser to xls or pdf

Tags: asp.net

I'm using MS Chart Control to generate reports as png files. How do I now make it possible for the user to click a button and download the report as xls or pdf?

ie. i have a png file on the client, is there any way to send this to the server to convert?

(ms chart control can only export to image or xml on the server side)

Comment: Can you give some more detail, I'm curious as to why you want to do that and what benefit you think it would bring for you. PNG is probably more likely to be viewable by your users than a PDF (ubiquitous as it is).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) to generate PDF and [Carlos AG](http://www.carlosag.net/) to generate XML using your PNG image as the content of the document. Then you can ouput your file using the response stream and an appropriate MIME type.

EDIT: are you using ASP.NET 4? If the answer is yes, there is a new Chart control that absolutely rocks!